# How to combine multiple similar columns in a dataset derived of multiple sources?

Tags: dataset, data-cleaning, metadata

I am trying to combine data from multiple sources. One issue I face is that the same columns are named differently. For example, the following refer to the same columns:

1. SampleID, sample id, sampleID, id, ID
2. Age, age, Age in years

These are just examples there are multiple columns like this.
I believe it is a common problem and hopefully good solutions already exist. If folks can point me what solutions/tools work best for this problem, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can rename the columns to match, if the different naming is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Yes, but the number of columns is in thousands. So manual renaming isn't optimal.